# How to convert Spearman's $\rho$, and Cramér's V to Cohen's $d$?

Tags: categorical-data, effect-size, spearman-rho, cohens-d, cramers-v

Is there a way to convert both, Spearman's $\rho$, and Cramér's V into the same effect size (f.e. Cohen's $d$), in order to have an information about which of the underlying relationships (nominal&ordinal --> Cramér's V; ordinal&ordinal --> Spearman's $\rho$) is stronger?

Fictitious example:
(a) Spearman's $\rho$: 0,4 --> Cohen's $d$: 0,34
(b) Cramér's V: 0,5 --> Cohen's $d$: 0,48

--> Relationship is stronger in case (b)?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but you seem to be implying that Spearman's $\rho$ only applies to ordinal data. That is not true: it is a valid measure of monotonic association regardless of data coding.

Comment: Yes and no. But I can't use Spearman's ρ to measure the relationship between one nominal (e.g. type of customer) and one categorial scaled variable (e.g. classes of income). Therefore I usually use Cramer's V, as it is written exemplarily here: http://bit.ly/UboHKV Or am I getting something wrong? Is there any orhter way to compare my effect sizes/correlations?

Comment: These effect size statistics are so different that I cannot imagine a way that you could convert among them.  Perhaps you could use standard interpretations of "small", "medium", and "large" to make some kind of relative comparison.  Also, I don't think you should be using Cramer's *V* for the association of nominal and ordinal variables.  It should be used for nominal and nominal variables.  For ordinal and nominal variables you might look at Freeman's *theta* or the *epsilon squared* that sometimes used with the Kruskal-Wallis test.

Answer (score 2):

There are formulas that let you convert between r and d. From the documentation of the [effectsize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effectsize/effectsize.pdf) R package:

[image]